# Automatically update all Apps

Tags: google-play-store, updates, application-autoupdate

I have some problems with the update feature for some apps. I cannot update them via Google Play, because there is no "Update" button, only the "Installed" button. However, there is clearly a new version (I've checked the version number of the installed app with the one offered by Google Play). Also, under "My Apps" in Settings, these apps are not listed, even though they are installed and run just fine.

What do I have to do, so that ALL apps can be updated, either automatically or manually through Google Play?

I am using a Nexus S with Android 4.1.2 installed.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Have you installed these non-updating apps from the Play store or from other sources (such as alternative stores or downloaded as .APK files)?

Comment: Most of them are from alternative sources indeed.

Comment: I think Titanium Backup has an option to **fix** market links for manually installed apps. I haven't used it myself though but its worth the try. I also know some other way to trick Google Play but is of questionable legality, use google if you want to know it.

Comment: If these are paid apps that you purchased from a third party market you have to use that market to update them, ie. Amazon Appstore. If they are free apps, look for the under the 'All' tab in Settings/Apps and try to uninstall them the reinstall them from Google Play.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Google Play --> Menu --> My Apps --> Update All

The "update all" should be near the top right corner. The default for most apps is "allow automatic updating". This can be changed for each app from this same screen by clicking on the app and checking the box "allow automatic updating".

BTW sometimes an app requires a manual update. The update all function will leave those out you have to click on each app and hit the UPDATE button.

I do know Google Play will not let you update an app if it thinks the update is not compatible with your version of software or hardware.